# How to see the amount of free disk space in files browser with 13.04 via terminal

Tags: command-line

I want to know how to see the DISK space using Terminal by command

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command to see the disk space available:

```
df
```

You can use
`df -h`
to make the output more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so, by using the [du](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du), and [df](http://linux.die.net/man/1/df) commands.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
df -h
```

You can also use

```
du -h
```

`du` shows the disk space used by the files and directories in the current directory.